# Laravel How to create a relationship between two Seeders

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-seeding

In my `laravel` app I have two tables in the database:

```
- education_categories
- educations
```

Now, I want to create two Seeders with a relationship between those to.

The EductionCategory Seeder:

```
public function run()
{
    DB::table('education_categories')->insert([
        'title' => "IT"
    ]);

    DB::table('education_categories')->insert([
        'title' => "Nature and science"
    ]);

    DB::table('education_categories')->insert([
        'title' => "Science"
    ]);

    DB::table('education_categories')->insert([
        'title' => "Construction"
    ]);

    ...etc
}
```

Now I want to have a Educations Seeder with some kind of a relationship to the Educations Category Seeder. Something like:

```
DB::table('educations')->insert([
    'title' => "Programmer",
    'education_categories_id' => 1
]);
```

Is this correct? Do I have to create `hasMany` relationship in my education_categories Model?

Answer (score -1):

Make two different models using `php artisan make:model ModelName` command in CLI and create relationship like this:

```
class TestRelationship extends Model {

public function testrelation()
  {
    return $this->hasMany('path\TestBelongs');
  }
}



  class TestBelongs extends Model {

    public function belongsme()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('path\TestRelationship');
    }

  }
```

Comment: Ah I see, what about the Seeder afterwards?